# parallel computing use Petsc in C

Tags: c, ubuntu, parallel-processing, linear-algebra, petsc

I learn how to use Petsc in C, I want to solve linear system with KSP ( find x in Ax=b, A is matrix(nxn), b is vector (n)) in Petsc. The library provides some tools to compute parallel in C. However, I have a trouble and find the answer, I hope to receive your explanation.

If I use A that has a size 5000x5000 (A is diagonally dominant matrix), it take a longer time to solve when I solve the problem without parallel. I do not understand the issue. Can you give me explanation, and how to do something to run faster?

My code that is in test.c is presented above:

```
#include <petscksp.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc,char **args)
{
  Vec            x, b, u;      /* approx solution, RHS, exact solution */
  Mat            A;            /* linear system matrix */
  KSP            ksp;          /* linear solver context */
  PC             pc;           /* preconditioner context */
  PetscReal      norm;         /* norm of solution error */
  PetscErrorCode ierr;
  PetscInt       i,n = 5000,col[5000],its , j,k;
  PetscMPIInt    size;
  PetscScalar    value[5000];
  PetscViewer    viewer;



  ierr = PetscInitialize(&argc,&args,(char*)0,help);if (ierr) return ierr;
  ierr = MPI_Comm_size(PETSC_COMM_WORLD,&size);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  if (size != 1) SETERRQ(PETSC_COMM_WORLD,1,"This is a uniprocessor example only!");
  ierr = PetscOptionsGetInt(NULL,NULL,"-n",&n,NULL);CHKERRQ(ierr);


  /* - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
         Compute the matrix and right-hand-side vector that define
         the linear system, Ax = b.
     - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - */

  /*
     Create vectors.  Note that we form 1 vector from scratch and
     then duplicate as needed.
  */
  ierr = VecCreate(PETSC_COMM_WORLD,&x);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = PetscObjectSetName((PetscObject) x, "Solution");CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = VecSetSizes(x,PETSC_DECIDE,n);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = VecSetFromOptions(x);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = VecDuplicate(x,&b);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = VecDuplicate(x,&u);CHKERRQ(ierr);

  /*
     Create matrix.  When using MatCreate(), the matrix format can
     be specified at runtime.

     Performance tuning note:  For problems of substantial size,
     preallocation of matrix memory is crucial for attaining good
     performance. See the matrix chapter of the users manual for details.
  */
  ierr = MatCreate(PETSC_COMM_WORLD,&A);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = MatSetSizes(A,PETSC_DECIDE,PETSC_DECIDE,n,n);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = MatSetFromOptions(A);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = MatSetUp(A);CHKERRQ(ierr);

  /*
     Assemble matrix
  */

/*value[0] = -1.0; value[1] = 1000.0; value[2] = -1.0;
  for (i=1; i<n-1; i++) {
    col[0] = i-1; col[1] = i; col[2] = i+1;
    ierr   = MatSetValues(A,1,&i,3,col,value,INSERT_VALUES);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  }
  i    = n - 1; col[0] = n - 2; col[1] = n - 1; value[1] = 1000.0; value[0] = -1.0;
  ierr = MatSetValues(A,1,&i,2,col,value,INSERT_VALUES);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  i    = 0; col[0] = 0; col[1] = 1; value[0] = 1000.0; value[1] = -1.0;
  ierr = MatSetValues(A,1,&i,2,col,value,INSERT_VALUES);CHKERRQ(ierr);*/

  for (i =0; i<n; i++){
    for (j=0; j<n;j++){

       value[j]= -2;
       if (j==i){
           value[j]= value[j] + 50000;
       }
    }
    for (k=0; k<n; k++){
       col[k]=k;
    }
    ierr = MatSetValues (A, 1, &i,n,col,value,INSERT_VALUES);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  }


  ierr = MatAssemblyBegin(A,MAT_FINAL_ASSEMBLY);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = MatAssemblyEnd(A,MAT_FINAL_ASSEMBLY);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  /* view matrix A*/
  //MatView(A,PETSC_VIEWER_STDOUT_WORLD);

  /*
     Set exact solution; then compute right-hand-side vector.
  */
  ierr = VecSet(u,1.0);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = MatMult(A,u,b);CHKERRQ(ierr);

  clock_t start, end;
  double cpu_time_used;
  start = clock();

  /* - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
                Create the linear solver and set various options
     - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - */
  ierr = KSPCreate(PETSC_COMM_WORLD,&ksp);CHKERRQ(ierr);

  /*
     Set operators. Here the matrix that defines the linear system
     also serves as the matrix that defines the preconditioner.
  */
  ierr = KSPSetOperators(ksp,A,A);CHKERRQ(ierr);

  /*
     Set linear solver defaults for this problem (optional).
     - By extracting the KSP and PC contexts from the KSP context,
       we can then directly call any KSP and PC routines to set
       various options.
     - The following four statements are optional; all of these
       parameters could alternatively be specified at runtime via
       KSPSetFromOptions();
  */
  ierr = KSPGetPC(ksp,&pc);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = PCSetType(pc,PCJACOBI);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = KSPSetTolerances(ksp,1.e-5,PETSC_DEFAULT,PETSC_DEFAULT,PETSC_DEFAULT);CHKERRQ(ierr);

  /*
    Set runtime options, e.g.,
        -ksp_type <type> -pc_type <type> -ksp_monitor -ksp_rtol <rtol>
    These options will override those specified above as long as
    KSPSetFromOptions() is called _after_ any other customization
    routines.
  */
  ierr = KSPSetFromOptions(ksp);CHKERRQ(ierr);

  /* - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
                      Solve the linear system
     - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - */
  ierr = KSPSolve(ksp,b,x);CHKERRQ(ierr);

  end = clock();
  cpu_time_used = ((double) (end - start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
  printf("take time: %lf \n",cpu_time_used );

  /* view solution */
  //ierr = VecView(x,PETSC_VIEWER_STDOUT_WORLD);CHKERRQ(ierr);


  /*
     View solver info; we could instead use the option -ksp_view to
     print this info to the screen at the conclusion of KSPSolve().
  */
  //ierr = KSPView(ksp,PETSC_VIEWER_STDOUT_WORLD);CHKERRQ(ierr);

  /* - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
                      Check the solution and clean up
     - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - */
  ierr = VecAXPY(x,-1.0,u);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = VecNorm(x,NORM_2,&norm);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = KSPGetIterationNumber(ksp,&its);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = PetscPrintf(PETSC_COMM_WORLD,"Norm of error %g, Iterations %D\n",(double)norm,its);CHKERRQ(ierr);

  /*
     Free work space.  All PETSc objects should be destroyed when they
     are no longer needed.
  */
  ierr = VecDestroy(&x);CHKERRQ(ierr); ierr = VecDestroy(&u);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = VecDestroy(&b);CHKERRQ(ierr); ierr = MatDestroy(&A);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = KSPDestroy(&ksp);CHKERRQ(ierr);




  /*
     Always call PetscFinalize() before exiting a program.  This routine
       - finalizes the PETSc libraries as well as MPI
       - provides summary and diagnostic information if certain runtime
         options are chosen (e.g., -log_view).
  */
  ierr = PetscFinalize();


  return ierr;
}
```

I run the program with command:

```
make test
mpirun -np 4 test
```

Comment: if you are going for a realtime execution test, then you should consider using multiple computer using `openmpi` , in a single computer the idea of `-np 4` is to create parallel child processes to make modular matrices and process it side by side

Comment: thank you for your respond, you mean that In order to run fatser, I need to use a lot of computers that use openmpi. If I have a computer that has 24 core, dose it  improve the effect of Petsc?

Comment: child process definitely improves the matrix manipulation for example `-np 4` create `four` child process, but you will not realize it visually, that is why I told multiple computers, it is naturally happening already, if you have 4 cores PC and another 8 core PC you can see a difference

Comment: Thank your for your reply so much, I understand my problem. In order to know, effect I will check the executing time with computer that have more 4 core,